# I want to download a vim release - but there are thousands!

Tags: vim, compiling, download

I want to download and build a release of vim, but on the [vim github repo](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases) - there are over 12,000 releases, and a release is made every few hours. What should I do?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to compile Vim yourself when your system's package system probably has a reasonable recent release available for you to install? The most interesting part of the Vim release number are the first two numbers.  The patch version is, as far as I know, a single commit's difference from the previous version.

Comment: Yes, every commit is tagged as a release... If you really want to build “a release”, presumably you could start by trying to build the latest one. As Kusalananda says though, unless you have a particular reason to build a release, you should use your distro’s packages; and if you do have a particular reason (*e.g.* you want a particular feature), that reason should tell you which release to build.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I need the python3 support. IIANM, I need to compile vim myself to get that - but would love to be proven wrong. I'm using Devuan Beowulf.

Comment: Perfect example of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270345), this.

Comment: @muru: Actually, it's an XYZ problem, because the reason I want a vim with python support is to enable code autocompletion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vim project has the slightly unusual custom to provide a new release *per source code commit*, with each commit incrementing the patch release number by 1. It's unlikely to matter too much what patch version of the latest major release you get, unless you want to get a *particular* patch.  Just use the latest release or the release packaged by your Unix system's package manager.

[In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658432/i-want-to-download-a-vim-release-but-there-are-thousands/658435#comment1239484_658432), it is revealed that what you actually want is a Vim with Python3 support, for Devuan Beowulf.

Using Devuan's [package search interface](https://pkginfo.devuan.org/cgi-bin/policy-query.html), it appears that [the `vim-nox` package](https://pkginfo.devuan.org/cgi-bin/package-query.html?c=package&q=vim-nox=2:8.1.0875-5) provides Vim with Python3 support:

> [...] This package contains a version of vim compiled with support for
> scripting with Lua, Perl, Python 3, Ruby, and Tcl but no GUI.

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit of a cryptic name for scripting support, but - saves me building my own version.

Comment: @einpoklum `nox` is short for "No X11 support", i.e. no GUI support.  You find that every once in a while in package names.

Comment: Sure, but why would I assume that has python support? :-(

Comment: @einpoklum why?  because the package description says "*Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with scripting languages support*".   BTW, `apt-cache` (which is iin the `apt` package, along with `apt` and `apt-get` etc) has a search feature - e.g. run `apt-cache search vim python` or with `-n` (which searches only the package name & provides lines) `apt-cache search -n vim python`